# How can I get geolocation information saved to my local state?

Tags: reactjs, axios, setstate, openweathermap

I'm trying to create a weather application that tells you the weather based on your geolocation. My intention was to take the geolocation info and set it to state, but the error I'm getting with the code below is that 'cannot read property setState of null'. The geolocation information is coming back just fine in my console, so retrieving the info isn't the issue. I'm guessing that it might have something to do with scope? Trying to come up with an alternative to get this information placed on my local state. I use the items on state to render in my JSX, but didn't think it was necessary to leave the JSX in there. Any thoughts or enlightenings?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      fahrenheit: "",
      celsius: "",
      image: "",
      description: "",
      location: ""
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocationInfo);
    } else { 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }


    function getLocationInfo(position) {
      axios.get(`http request info here`)   
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                  description: response.data.weather[0].description
                  fahrenheit: response.data.main.temp,
                  image: response.data.weather[0].icon,
                  location: response.data.main.name
                })
              })
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Do not use the function keyword to define a method of a class

To use `setState` you must be use a class method, this is a function without the function keyword in its definition. Your current bug comes from haveing a different context for the this keyword.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fahrenheit: "",
      celsius: "",
      image: "",
      description: "",
      location: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocationInfo);
    } else { 
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }


  getLocationInfo(position) {
    axios.get(`http request info here`)   
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
              description: response.data.weather[0].description
              fahrenheit: response.data.main.temp,
              image: response.data.weather[0].icon,
              location: response.data.main.name
            })
       })
   }
 }
```